# Android-like plugin for web development in Eclipse

Tags: php, html, eclipse, plugins, web

I have been developing web applications and sites for almost 3 years now. The languages I use are PHP, JS, and HTML, using Aptana. About 1 year ago, I started doing Android dev as well, using the ADT plugin for Eclipse. Soon after, I completely fell in love with the way Android organizes / integrates different file types, and how they interact. For example, you do not you don't just inline Android Java in XML files, and vice versa. Specific Android methods are used to manipulate XML functions in a transparent way, and it is extremely easy to avoid mixing GUI functionality with actual app functionality.

What I'm looking for is something similar for web dev. For example, call a PHP function such as `page->getButton('id')->setText('text');` to manipulate HTML, and then edit the actual HTML seperately for specific tweaking if necessary. I generally use jQuery for similar functionality, but this is hardly a solution to my problem as I generally need to inline PHP in HTML anyway. I am aware of some wysiwig editors out there, but the excessive amount of garbage code they generate makes me lose all respect for the idea of using them.

Are there any good plugins / classes out there that do what I'm looking for? I'm getting to the point where I'm considering writing my own Eclipse plugins in my spare time to do what I want.

Comment: PHP/JS/HMTL always have that separation of logic. What you are looking for is more relevant for software programming, not just web programming. You should really take a look to the .NET platform, which is closer to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - I have never really thought of looking into .NET, because my company runs Linux servers and refuses to use proprietary software. I will definitely look into it out of interest, though.